# How can website detect whether a particular browser (Chrome) is installed on that PC?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, browser

This is probably "no" but wanted to check.

Is there any way for a website to detect whether the Chrome browser is installed on a Windows PC?

Would be acceptable if it only worked within IE (in case IE has some magical access to more info in the Registry than other browsers)

Comment: No, there isn't. Allowing a website that kind of access to your PC would be a hideous security/privacy vulnerability. You rpobably could with IE, but even then you'd need an activex control to do the back-end digging, and activex was/is/always will be a steaming pile of feces.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is possible to do via an ActiveX plugin (which checks for the presence of certain installed registry keys), but this is normally not something that a web application should be doing, and I would recommend against it. See the following:

[How to detect whether a particular software is installed in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995482/how-to-detect-whether-a-particular-software-is-installed-in-windows)

Comment: Miles, that link appears to be to C++ code that checks on the SERVER.  I tried looking for an Active X control for this but found nothing.